# Jquery Mobile - Javascript persisting when navigating to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Hey guys I have a javascript function that keeps persisting even when navigating to another page (single page templates not multipage) in Jquery Mobile

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       setInterval("window.location.reload();", 5000);
    </script>
```

How do I ensure that this only occurs on the page from which it is called rather than it calling it on every page I link to with ajax based navigation?

I am using Jquery Mobile 1.2

Comment: In a singe page template, you never navigate away, therefore this is the expected behaviour.

Comment: Sorry about that there were quite a few typos.  I meant jquery mobile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind it to the page where you want it to occur. Replace *`$('.selector')`* with pageID, e.g. `$('#home')`. You could also be more specific `$('div[data-role="page"]#PageID')`.

```
// Trigger interval
$('.selector').bind('pageinit', function () {
 setInterval("window.location.reload();", 5000);
});

// Stop interval when navigating away
$('.selector').bind('pagehide', function () {
 clearInterval();
});
```

Comment: Thanks this fixed the issue easily.  I just added a page id to the page, and then set the page initialization to intiate the interval.  When leaving the page on the page hide event it kills the interval.

Comment: @user2100493 you could assign an ID for the `setInterval` in case you have several ones in order not to kill them all by `clearInterval`. Glad I've been of help :)

Comment: Yes I wish I could honestly check mark two answers as the below answers helped me not kill off all my intervals as well.  I assigned the interval into a variable.  Your answer though was the most comprehensive one, so I figured this answer would help the majority of people googling for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I ensure that this only occurs on the page from which it is
>   called rather than it calling it on every page I link to with ajax
>   based navigation?

Don't call it? Currently your code is set up to *always* run when it's included on the page. Either don't include it or prevent it from running in some other way (such as an if-statement).

Answer (score 2):

You could clear the interval just before you navigate.

First you need to get a reference to the interval when you create it:

```
var intervalRef = setInterval("window.location.reload();", 5000);
```

Then you can clear it like this:

```
clearInterval(intervalRef);
// Navigate
```

Answer (score 2):

Just cancel your timeout when the other page loads, or when the current page exits (the other page loads in ajax so the timed interval stays up).

```
// trigger
myInterval = setInterval("window.location.reload();", 5000);

// stop
clearInterval(myInterval);
```